# Need advice on hardware stack for Wireless Audio solution

Tags: audio, arduino, raspberry-pi

Good day!

**Problem definition:**
Current implementations of Bluetooth does not allow to simply support good quality of Audio(Earphones mode) and 2-way audio transition (Headset mode).
Also, even if one would manage to set this configuration up, which have huge limitations on the hardware/software used, there is no way to handle sound input from 2 different audio devices simultaneously.
So, technically - one cannot just play the Game, communicate on the Discord, and optionally listen to some music, unless he is bound to some USB-bundled earphones. Which are usually really crappy, or really expensive. Or both.

**Solution sketch:**
So, I came up with an idea that one can actually build such device, using **Raspberry Pi**, **Arduino**, or even **barebone-component-based** stacks.

Theoretical layout of connections per-se would look somehow like that:
[image]

Idea is to create 2 "simple" devices

- One, not-so-portable, that would handle several analog inputs, and one analog output
- One, portable, that would handle single analog Input and Output, and could be used with any analog earphones.

"Requirements" to such system would be quite simple:

- This bundle have to handle Data Transition on some distance, preferably up to 10 meters, or more.
- The "Inlet" device should be portable enough to keep it in the pocket, or in an arm band, or something
- Sound Quality should be at the very least on the level of Bluetooth headphones profile, or if possible - even better
- If possible - it would be nice to keep the price of the Solution under 500 Euros, but I'm so tired of current state of things that I might consider raising the budget...
- Don't mind the yellow buttons on the Outlet device. Those are optional, and will depend on the implementation stack :)

**Question:**
Can anyone advice me which component-base would be a better solution to making such a tool, and why?
And maybe someone actually knows of similar systems already existing?

Personally I would prefer anything but the **barebone-components-based** solution, just because I'm really rusty with that area, and it requires quite the amount of tools, to handle it properly.
While using pre-built modules can save me from buying most of the hardware tools, minifying my "hardware customization" part of this solution, leaving only software part to handle (which is my main area of expertise).
But then again, if there are some experts here, that would consider other stacks non-viable - I would really appreciate to see their reasonings.

P.S. Just to be clear: If this project will prove viable - I will implement it, and share the implementation details with the communities. I am not the first one who needs such system, and unfortunately it seems that Hardware/Software vendors are not really interested in designing similar solutions...

Answer (score 0):

I happen to find a "temporary" solution.

I've came across a wireless headset, that allows to simultaneously support `Wireless USB Bundle` connection, and `Bluetooth` connection to different devices, and provide nice way of controlling sound input/output with both connections.

This was almost a pure luck, as this "feature" was not described anywhere in the specs...

Actual headset name is:

> JBL Quantum 800

This does not closes the question per-se, as I still plan to implement this "Summer Project" at some point, but I believe this information might be useful to those searching for similar solutions.